# Different pulic key for jump host and destination host over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I have HOP server (bastion) and APP server. I am able to ssh to HOP server via:

```
$ ssh HOP
```

I am able to ssh to APP server from HOP server:

```
$ ssh APP
```

Both SSH works without password, only via ssh keys.

During ansible deploy I find out I cannot connect to APP server via HOP. I am testing it over cmd:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p HOP" APP
```

After this, I am able to connect to APP server but it requires password. I find out, even when APP ssh works from HOP, now it cannot detect configuration from HOP server. So I defined the public key to use  in command line:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p HOP" APP -i /etc/ssh/my_ssh_key
Warning: Identity file /etc/ssh/my_ssh_key not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

But now, It tried to locate **my_ssh_key** on localhost, and it asks for password again.

How can I force the use configuration from HOP server or define to use SSH public key from HOP and not from localhost? Is it even possible?

Comment: I would recommended to use "Forward agent " config if you are using the same key. it is much more secure. you can use this configuration in Ansible also.
"Host <HOP server name or IP>
  ForwardAgent Yes"

Comment: As I write in the header, there are different keys. So I set ForwardAgent to no. So it cannot be used as you mentioned, right? Do you have any idea how to solve this? If there would be the same key, I would just need to ssh-add and then used ForwardAgent yes, right?

Comment: Yes. you can add your keys to agent by running: ssh-add <your key location>. you can verify by running : ssh-add -L 
then you can make config in local  host - from where you are  ssh'ng HOP/APP. create ~/.ssh/config, in case file is not present then add:
Host <IP or name of HOP/APP>
  ForwardAgent yes

Comment: But that mean, I have to have all ssh keys on my localhost. As I mentioned above, I have only key to HOP, not from HOP to APP.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by following this approach:

Ansible host file changes to use bastion host under host group:

```
 [testservers]
 192.168.20.140
 192.168.10.88
[testservers:vars]
ansible_port = 22 # remote host port
ansible_user = ec2-user # remote user host
private_key_file = /Users/laptop-ansibleuser/.ssh/id_rsa # laptop key to login to bastion host
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o \'ForwardAgent yes\' ansible-remote@<bastion host> -p 2222 \'ssh-add /home/ansible-remote/.ssh/id_rsa && nc %h %p\'"'
```