# Need to use ansible to connect to a host via a jump host using a key in the jump host

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have a machine that is accessible through a jump host.

What I need is this.

A is my local machine

B is the jump host

C is the destination machine

I need to connect to C using ansible via B but use a private key in B.

Current config is the inventory file is as shown below

```
    [deployment_host:vars]
ansible_port = 22 # remote host port
ansible_user = <user_to_the_Target_machine> # remote user host
private_key_file = <key file to bastion in my laptop> # laptop key to login to bastion host
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o \'ForwardAgent yes\' <user>@<bastion> -p 2222 \'ssh-add /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa && nc %h 22\'"'
[deployment_host]
10.200.120.218  ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

How can I do that

I have not made any changes to my ssh config and when i run ansible like below

```
ansible -vvv all -i inventory.ini -m shell -a 'hostname'
```

I get this error

```
ansible 2.9.0
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.5 (default, May 11 2021, 08:20:37) [GCC 10.3.0]
No config file found; using defaults
host_list declined parsing /root/temp_ansible/inventory.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /root/temp_ansible/inventory.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /root/temp_ansible/inventory.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method
yaml declined parsing /root/temp_ansible/inventory.ini as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /root/temp_ansible/inventory.ini inventory source with ini plugin
META: ran handlers
<10.200.120.218> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: <user> # remote user host
<10.200.120.218> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="<user> # remote user host"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -o '"'"'ForwardAgent yes'"'"' <user>@35.223.214.105 -p 2222 '"'"'ssh-add /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa && nc %h 22'"'"'' -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ec0480070b 10.200.120.218 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'~<user> # remote user host'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.200.120.218> (255, b'', b'kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host\r\nConnection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535\r\n')
10.200.120.218 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host\r\nConnection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: You've already provided main parts of the configuration for "_Running Ansible through SSH Jump / Bastion Host_". Because of this post, are you experience any errors?

Comment: yes, it is trying to use the ssh key from my machine, how can i get this to use the key that is in jump host that is B

Comment: Why do you `ForwardAgent yes` if you don't want to use keys from the original host?

Comment: Does [SSH from A through B to C using private key on B](https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/) answer your question?

Comment: I did look at this https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/. But then again, no one actually explains the scenario where I need to use the key that is not at all in my local. The key is in the home/.ssh folder of the user in jump host.

Comment: Regarding "_no one actually explains the scenario where I need to use the key that is not at all in my local_" for me it looks like that the answers https://serverfault.com/a/701884/448950 and https://serverfault.com/a/965555/448950 are doing exactly that.

Comment: yes, sorry for that comment, but I am not able to integrate this into ansible. Integrating this with ansible is where I am getting stuck at. From ssh it works, but when i add the ansible inventory that i pasted in OP, it gives permission error as it is looking for the key in my local laptop(even without ForwardAgent)

Comment: Can you than update your question with the configuration which you are using, where you've added the `ssh-add`  part and which is not working, as well with meaningful output and error messages?

Comment: Maybe this helps you out [Different pubKey for jump host and destination host over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68843493/6771046).

Comment: Your recent update seems not to contain the `ssh-add` part.

Comment: i have updated the OP @U880D

Comment: So your are experience an [Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535](https://serverfault.com/a/1070452/448950).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239147/discussion-between-sharath-prakash-and-u880d).

Comment: yes. I am facing that but why is it using 65535 instead of 22

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.

For me this was
adding both entries of my server A and B into the ~/.ssh/config

```
Host bastion1
    HostName <IP/FQDN>
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    User <USER>
    IdentityFile <File to log into the first bastion server> # should be present in your local machine.
Host bastion2
    HostName <IP/FQDN>
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    User <USER>
    IdentityFile <File to log into the second bastion server> # should be present in your local machine. 
    ProxyJump bastion
```

Then editing the inventory file like shown below.

```
[deployment_host]
VM_IP  ansible_user=<vm_user> ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<file to login to VM> 
[deployment_host:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-J bastion1,bastion2'
```

Then any ansible command with this inventory should work without issue

```
❯ ansible all -i inventory.ini -m shell -a "hostname"
<VM_IP> | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
development-host-1
```

> NOTE: All these ssh keys should be in your local system. You can get
> the bastion2 private key from bastion1 using ansible and the same for
> the VM from bastion2 using ansible ad-hoc fetch